# restrict put, delete and options request in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have used following code to restrict put, delete and options request in my web app but the test response shows *200 OK*.

Any suggestion?

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(customLogOutHandler()).permitAll();

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").denyAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**").denyAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").denyAll();

        super.configure(http);
        http.cors();

    }
```

Comment: Remove `super.configure(http);`, it overwrites your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `super.configure(http);` which will override your configuration with below and *denyAll()* will not deny the request with methods

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin().and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to configure Spring Security so that access to particular URL patterns are secured differently depending on the HTTP method used to access the URL pattern.

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/path/to/deny").denyAll(); 

http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/you/can/alsoSpecifyAPath").denyAll(); 

http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/and/can/haveWildcards/*").denyAll();
```

Comment: used this, not worked  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").denyAll(); 
  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/**").denyAll(); 
  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/**").denyAll();

Comment: @SakshamGoel Please try for a particulat URL pattern